# Correlated Subqueries - Counting records "less than" the main query record

Tags: mysql, sql, correlated-subquery

I am attempting to determine which "iteration" any given record is by counting the number of records that preceded it and have certain matching characteristics. Essentially, I'd like to know the number of records with the same parent record & category that also have an ID#  less than [my record's ID#]. I can get a correlated subquery to count the number of records with the same parent and category, but when I try to add an ID filter, my subquery filter can't find the column "T1.ID" - the ID# field from my main table.

My SQL follows, the asterisks are where I've tried and failed to limit results based on "T1's" record ID (I obviously exclude the asterisks in my actual SQL)

```
select T1.ID, T2.ITERATION
from TICKET as T1
inner join
(select COUNT(T3.ID) as ITERATION, T3.CATEGORY_ID, T3.PARENT_ID 
from TICKET as T3 
where T3.IS_PARENT = 0 **AND T3.ID < T1.ID**
group by T3.PARENT_ID, T3. CATEGORY_ID)
as T2 on (T1.PARENT_ID = T2.PARENT_ID AND
T1. CATEGORY_ID = T2.CATEGORY_ID)
where T1.IS_PARENT = 0
```

I other programs, I've used functions that build a subquery to accomplish a similar result, so if I should be looking in that direction instead, I'd appreciate that feedback.

I'm counting from the same table, so sample data:

```
ID   PARENT_ID    CATEGORY
10   1            A
11   2            A
12   1            B
13   3            A
14   2            A
15   1            A
16   3            B
17   1            A
```

And desired output:

```
ID   ITERATION    (explanation)
10   0            (No preceding ID with same parent & category)
11   0            (No preceding ID with same parent & category)
12   0            (No preceding ID with same parent & category)
13   0            (No preceding ID with same parent & category)
14   1            (ID 11 precedes 14 and shares parent & category)
15   1            (ID 10 precedes 15 and shares parent & category)
16   0            (No preceding ID with same parent & category)
17   2            (ID's 10, 15 precede 17 and share parent & category)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    PARENT_ID, 
    CATEGORY, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TICKET 
     WHERE ID < T.ID 
          AND CATEGORY = T.CATEGORY 
          AND PARENT_ID = T.PARENT_ID
     ) AS ITERATION
FROM TICKET T
ORDER BY ID
```

Result using your sample data:

```
ID  PARENT_ID   CATEGORY    ITERATION
10  1           A           0
11  2           A           0
12  1           B           0
13  3           A           0
14  2           A           1
15  1           A           1
16  3           B           0
17  1           A           2
```